# read a double number from file - c

Tags: c

I have file filled with rows of data:
each row contains:
'char' space 'double'. e.g:

```
a 17.322\n
c 9.45\n
```

I want to 'eat' the \n and the char, and read only the double number.
what is the best way to do it.

thanks, and sorry if I have English mistakes

Comment: Please produce minimum code tried by you for get solution

Comment: I thought to use fgetc() twice. but maybe there is a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simple `fscanf` can do the job

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test", "r");
    float n;

    while(fscanf(f, "%*[a-z]%f ", &n) == 1)
        printf("%f, ", n);

    return 0;
}
```

- `"%*"` ignores everything it reads
- `"[a-z]"` reads characters from range 'a' to 'z'
- `"%f"` reads a single precision floating point number (in other words `float`)
- `" "` ignores all [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)
- [fscanf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) returns `EOF` in case of reading error (ex. end of file) or **number of read values** which in our case is 1

Comment: wo thanks!! does `" "` ignores /n ?

Comment: Since it falls under [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) definition, yes

Comment: yep, thank you!!